# Scaling Radio Buttons

Tags: css, firefox

I need help scaling radio buttons. Chrome, and IE11 work fine using transform, scale. However, Firefox the borders are blurry and looks horrible. Any help would be great!

```css
    p { float: left; margin: 5px }

    input {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
        -o-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
        transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
    }
```

```html
    <p><input type="radio" name="foo"></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="foo"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/applesElmi/ueafvmcx/

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, in 2020 I'm having the reverse problem where Firefox's radio buttons look fine scaled up, but Chrome's are a pixelated mess.

Comment: Also in 2020, I'm still having this problem.  Firefox's radio buttons with transform: scale(x) look terrible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferent web browsers have different rendering engines and parsing methods ... if you want it to work on FF don't use scale ... try a different approach or wait for FF update to solve that.

Here you have a nice tutorial on how to customize checkboxes/radio buttons: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

HTML

```
<div class="radio">  
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">  
    <label for="male">Male</label>  
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">  
    <label for="female">Female</label>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  
    padding-left: 25px;  
    margin-right: 15px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
} 

input[type=radio] {  
    display: none;  
}  


label:before {  
    content: "";  
    display: inline-block;  

    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  

    margin-right: 10px;  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    bottombottom: 1px;  
    background-color: #aaa;  
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}
```